# Solve the heat equation by PDE Toolbox of Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, math-software

I try to use Matlab to solve heat equation 
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-\Delta u=0      \\
u|_{t=0}=1-x^2-y^2  \\
u|_{\partial\Omega}=0\\
\Omega: x^2 + y^2 \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
Pictures below is the parameter I using, but obviously, the result is  wrong, since when $t=0$, the maximum of $u$ is $1$, but when $t=10$, the maximum of $u$ is bigger than $1$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pay attention to the scaling of the axis. According to the last picture the maximal height is no more than $2 \cdot 10^{-11}$.

Comment: @Andrew  Thanks, I am  too thoughtless.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. :)